# SQLite obtener datos de una tabla

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos soy nuevo trabajando con SQLite y tengo una pregunta, ya por fin conseguí hacer mi tabla y hasta meterle datos (wow), pero lo que quisiera saber es si alguien sabe como confirmar si dicha tabla está o no vacía ? y en caso de que lo esté , ya saben tirar otra función etc ... este es mi code ...

```js
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SqlieTest_x
{
   public class MemberDatabase
    {
        private SQLiteConnection conn;

        public MemberDatabase() {
            conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();        
                conn.CreateTable<Member>();    
        }

        public IEnumerable<Member> GetMembers() {
            var members = (from mem in conn.Table<Member>() select mem);
            return members.ToList();
        }

        public string AddMember(Member member) {
            conn.Insert(member);
            return "success baby bluye ;*";
        }

        public string DeleteMember(int id) {
            conn.Delete(id);
            return "success user deleted";
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito algo para poder evaluar la respuesta  **GetMembers**, en esta vista, estoy instanciando la bd, pero saber su contenido antes de que me lo devuelva a un a la vista, alguien cree saber como ayudarme?

```js
   public MemberDatabase memberDatabase;
        public Member member;
        public FormsPage ()
  {
   InitializeComponent ();
            memberDatabase = new MemberDatabase();
            var members = memberDatabase.GetMembers();
           /* if (members != null) // o algo similar que me permita saber su contenido
           //previo a la consulta
            {
                DisplayAlert("no","no members", "i accept");
            }*/
            xlist.ItemsSource = members;
        }
```

Comment: Tu condicional if no te sirve para evaluar eso? Te arroja algún error?

Comment: no , lo que pasa es que el la tabla no va a ser null, dado que siempre existe con y sin contenido, eso no me manda ningún error, pero tampoco la estoy consultado como deseo, ¿si me explico? @Lucas.D

Comment: Entiendo. Quieres saber si tu tabla tiene o no filas/registros ?

Comment: yesh plish mr.Lucas

Comment: Tu nueva pregunta creo que la borraste, te dejo esto, espero te sirva:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/120332/how-to-add-background-service-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: por cierto, fui yo quien te puso el -1. Llevas tiempo en el sitio y deberías conocer cómo funciona al respecto, la medalla de informado también la tienes https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed?userid=57794 evita tomar a mal ese -1, sé que te quedó ese "mal sabor" con el que sí o sí vas a mejorar, el espíritu de aprender y mejorar lo tienes, a veces sólo se necesita un empujoncito espartano :D

Comment: @fredyfx gracias fredy , no la verdad no, no me tomo mal esas cosas, al contrario, agradesco mucho tu tiempo que siempre tomas para contestarme. Un abrazo :D

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para elevar el cosmos y darle con todo el power 2.0!!! StackOverflow me ha ayudado muchísimo a crecer como persona y como profesional al igual que muchos de los que visitan el sitio. Además me ha conectado con gente cheeere que tiene esa pasión por el desarrollo de software, ¡una hermandad muy padre! Entra a la sala de chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol los hermanos de SOes son muy buena onda, voy por el almuerzo, regreso al rato, un abrazo hermano :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A {

   SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
   cmd.CommandText = "select * from table";
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   int RowCount = 0;

   RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

   if (RowCount > 0) { //hay registros... }
   else {//no hay registros}

}
```

Comment: Lucas no creo que esto me sirva, porque esto es para asp.net con sql server me imagino, y yo estoy ocupando SQLite desde xamarin

Comment: Bien, no leí los tags, disculpa. Ahora veo si encuentro una solución que se adapte a lo que buscas.

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim . Actualice mi respuesta con lo que pude encontrar, me avisas si te sirve.

Comment: te amo deja pruebo y si si, te doy la respuesta

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim no es necesario una edicion. El if que propenes esta al revés, si RowCount es mayor a 0 es porque hay registros.